# Can't install RMagick 2.13.2

Tags: ruby, macos, imagemagick, rmagick

I am having an issue on OS X Maverick when trying to install the rmagick gem. Following are some details

ImageMagic details

```
mairs-MacBook-Pro:social-login-in-rails umair$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-1 Q16 x86_64 2014-07-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules
Delegates: bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png xml zlib
```

I tried installing with and without paths but I am unable to install rmagick.
Error on installing rmagick

```
Umairs-MacBook-Pro:social-login-in-rails umair$ sudo C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/include/ImageMagick-6/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/Users/umair/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:73: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/umair/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes

Warning: Found more than one ImageMagick installation. This could cause problems at runtime.
     /usr/local/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.8.9 Q16 is installed in /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-1
     /opt/ImageMagick/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.8.8 Q16 is installed in /opt/ImageMagick
Using 6.8.9 Q16 from /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-1.

checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 41: pkg-config: command not found
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 47: pkg-config: command not found
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 50: pkg-config: command not found
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 53: pkg-config: command not found
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 53: pkg-config: command not found
Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/umair/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/umair/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/umair/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/rmagick-2.13.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: how did you include it in your gem file?

Comment: just wrote gem 'rmagick' in gemfile. But I am not installing it from bundle install. I have pasted exact command which I am using to install

Answer (score 5):

For anyone having issues with this on OSX Sierra with homebrew installing imagemagick version 7+

You need to install version 6 of imagemagick in order for rmagick to work properly. These 3 commands worked for me. Install the version 6 of imagemagick and then force it to link. bundle installing rmagick should work properly afterwards.

```
$ brew install imagemagick@6

$ brew link imagemagick@6 --force

$ bundle install
```

You may need to `brew uninstall imagemagick` before installing and linking to @6.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and running these on the command line fixed it (using mac):

```
$ brew uninstall pkg-config
$ brew install pkg-config
$ brew unlink pkg-config && brew link pkg-config
```

Answer (score 1):

For a clean install of `imagemagick@6` required for `rmagic 2.16` you need to run:

```
$ brew uninstall imagemagick
$ brew install imagemagick@6 && brew link imagemagic@6 --force
$ brew install pkg-config
```

Then you yould be able to run `bundle install` without issues.